# SQL joining most recent event by criteria to missing value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table that records interactions and the changes that happen in an interaction by interactionkey, user, group, and skill. I want to find the duration of each of the actions (A,B,C) by the grouping variables. Whenever action C happens, the skillKey is left blank (not NULL) and I need it to take the value of the last Skill in that interaction by the user and group so it is grouped together. The first table is the raw SQL data for 1 interaction, and the second is how I need it to look. Edit: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Here's what I have so far but it doesn't account for the last skill the user used in the group and interactionkey so it remains blank and adds it up seperately

```
SELECT 
    [InteractionKey], 
    [User],
    [StartTime],
    [SkillKey],
    [GroupKey],
    SUM(CASE WHEN ActionKey = 'A' THEN ActionDuration ELSE 0 END) AS 'ActionADuration',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ActionKey = 'B' THEN ActionDuration ELSE 0 END) AS 'ActionBDuration',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ActionKey = 'C' THEN ActionDuration ELSE 0 END) AS 'ActionCDuration'
FROM
    (SELECT
         [ActionKey],
         [InteractionKey],
         [SkillKey],
         [GroupKey],
         SUM(ActionDuration) AS 'ActionDuration',
         [User],
         CAST(StartTime AS DATE)
     FROM 
         [InteractionTable]
     GROUP BY 
         InteractionKey, User, SkillKey, GroupKey, ActionKey, 
         CAST(StartTime AS DATE)) sub 
GROUP BY 
    InteractionKey, User, Date, SkillKey, GroupKey
ORDER BY 
    InteractionKey
```

Raw SQL Server table:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: And what's wrong with your current query?

Comment: My current query does not match the last skill to the missing value and just groups it as a blank character

Comment: In your Desired output, how do you get '12/1/2018 13:30'?  I don't see it in the raw data.

Comment: I need to solve for that portion too, but that should be considerably easier than the issue with getting the appropriate skill added. Its supposed to be what 30 minute interval the interaction started in.

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.  List clearly what you want to achieve,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry, but what don't you understand? I feel I'm being clear here. Basically I need to make the first blank value in skillkey, A, since the last interaction Tom took in group B with that interactionKey ID has a skill Key of A. The 2nd one should also be A, then C, then B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to prepare another "table" with SkillKey already filled as you need, and then use this table in your query.

I will use `CTE` in my code,
and it is different for divverent versions of `SQL Server`.
The first one is preferable, but it's for servers starting with `2012`.
If you are on lower version use the second query.

```
-- for @@version >= 2012
with cte as
(
select *, 
       case 
           when SkillKey <> '' 
           then SkillKey
           else lag(SkillKey) over(partition by InteractionKey, [User], GroupKey order by [Date])
       end as SkillKey
from InteractionTable
)

SELECT 
    [InteractionKey], 
    [User],
    [StartTime],
    [SkillKey],
    [GroupKey],
    SUM(CASE WHEN ActionKey = 'A' THEN ActionDuration ELSE 0 END) AS 'ActionADuration',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ActionKey = 'B' THEN ActionDuration ELSE 0 END) AS 'ActionBDuration',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ActionKey = 'C' THEN ActionDuration ELSE 0 END) AS 'ActionCDuration'
FROM
    (SELECT
         [ActionKey],
         [InteractionKey],
         [SkillKey],
         [GroupKey],
         SUM(ActionDuration) AS 'ActionDuration',
         [User],
         CAST(StartTime AS DATE)
     FROM 
         cte
     GROUP BY 
         InteractionKey, User, SkillKey, GroupKey, ActionKey, 
         CAST(StartTime AS DATE)) sub 
GROUP BY 
    InteractionKey, User, Date, SkillKey, GroupKey
ORDER BY 
    InteractionKey
```

The second:

```
-- for @@version >= 2005

with r as
(
select *,
       row_number() over(partition by InteractionKey, [User], GroupKey order by [Date]) as rn
from InteractionTable
)

,cte as
(
select r1.*,
       case 
           when r1.SkillKey <> '' 
           then r1.SkillKey
           else r2.SkillKey
       end as SkillKey

from r r1
     left join r r2
        on r1.rn = r2.rn + 1
)
SELECT 
    [InteractionKey], 
    [User],
    [StartTime],
    [SkillKey],
    [GroupKey],
    SUM(CASE WHEN ActionKey = 'A' THEN ActionDuration ELSE 0 END) AS 'ActionADuration',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ActionKey = 'B' THEN ActionDuration ELSE 0 END) AS 'ActionBDuration',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ActionKey = 'C' THEN ActionDuration ELSE 0 END) AS 'ActionCDuration'
FROM
    (SELECT
         [ActionKey],
         [InteractionKey],
         [SkillKey],
         [GroupKey],
         SUM(ActionDuration) AS 'ActionDuration',
         [User],
         CAST(StartTime AS DATE)
     FROM 
         cte
     GROUP BY 
         InteractionKey, User, SkillKey, GroupKey, ActionKey, 
         CAST(StartTime AS DATE)) sub 
GROUP BY 
    InteractionKey, User, Date, SkillKey, GroupKey
ORDER BY 
    InteractionKey
```